# AWS EC2 Public DNS and Public ip show refused to connect on browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

On My AWS ec2 can not access via bowser is say refused to connect. um add all inbond and also check firewall its enable
[Firewall enable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzHdp.png)

[EC2 inbound and outbound rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3A1W.png)

i can connect via ssh and install LAMP

Comment: What command are you using to connect?

Comment: Is your instance in a public subnet?

Comment: its Fixed . when click there link its go via https but i don't have SSL that why its show an error.

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 allows only instances with Amazon Linux 2 AMI to connect via the browser. If you had launched your instance using AMI other than Amazon Linux 2 then you have to log in to the EC2 instance using SSH.

If you had launched the instance using Amazon Linux 2 and still facing the problem of connecting via a browser then check if your instance is running in the public subnet.